# remove specific symbols from object files

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I want to remove the following symbols from object files which are compiled using gcc for arm platform

```
.debug_frame
.debug_line
.debug_aranges
.debug_info
.debug_ranges
```

I am using the following compilation flags

```
-mcpu-cortex-r4f -march=armv7-r -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -std=gnu99
```

what should be added or removed to avoid the mentioned symbols

Comment: See the `strip` command. The general use is `strip -s filename` to `(--strip-all)` symbols. For `debug` symbols `strip -S`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> See the `strip` command. The general use is `strip -s filename` to `(--strip-all)` symbols. For `debug` symbols `strip -S`.

–  This was answered by [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) in the comments under this question.