# Can gcc not include debug info from crt*.o?

Tags: c, gcc, crt

I am using Ghidra for some binary analysis, but it doesn't support DWARF 5:

> ghidra.app.util.bin.format.dwarf4.DWARFException: Only DWARF version 2, 3, or 4 information is currently supported.

Okay fine, I'll rebuild everything with `-gdwarf-4 -gstrict-dwarf` ...

> ghidra.app.util.bin.format.dwarf4.DWARFException: Only DWARF version 2, 3, or 4 information is currently supported.

Hmm, what's going on?

> ```console
> $ cat foo.c
> int main() {
>         return 0;
> }
> $ gcc -gdwarf-4 -gstrict-dwarf foo.c -o foo
> $ readelf -w foo
> ...
>   Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
>    Length:        0x24 (32-bit)
>    Version:       5
>    Unit Type:     DW_UT_compile (1)
>    Abbrev Offset: 0x0
>    Pointer Size:  8
>  <0><c>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
>     <d>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0
>     <11>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x1020
>     <19>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 38
>     <1a>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): ../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S
>     <1e>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x1a): /build/glibc/src/glibc/csu
>     <22>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x35): GNU AS 2.38
> ...
> ```

Ah, there's a bunch of DWARF 5 debug info from `crti.o` and friends.  Can I tell gcc or ld to omit them from the binary, while keeping my own debug info?

Comment: Is there anything here ( [about excluding object files from build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10280945/645128))?

Comment: @ryyker I mean, I still need to link the C runtime.  I just want to skip their `.debug_info` sections.

Comment: [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27184733/645128) then

Comment: Update: this problem has "solved itself" for me as the latest GCC package on Arch Linux is built with separate debug info.  Ghidra doesn't try to load that, so `-gdwarf-4` is now enough.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this hacky approach: first, first, figure out which crt objects are being linked by passing `-v` to the linker:

```
$ gcc -Wl,-v foo.c -o foo
collect2 version 12.1.0
/usr/bin/ld -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccsoyfj1.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -o foo /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../.. -v /tmp/ccDNayjM.o -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib/crtn.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.38
```

Next, strip them manually:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

crt=(
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib/crti.o
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/crtbeginS.o
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/crtendS.o
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib/crtn.o
)

for obj in "${crt[@]}"; do
    objcopy -R .debug_info -R .debug_aranges -R .debug_line "$obj" "./$(basename "$obj")"
done

gcc -gdwarf-4 -gstrict-dwarf -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc -nostartfiles Scrt1.o crti.o crtbeginS.o foo.o crtendS.o crtn.o -o foo
```

And it works!

```
$ readelf -w foo | grep -i version
  Version:               1
  Version:                  2
   Version:       4
  DWARF Version:               4
```